# MEAN.IO multiple package with their own template

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean, meanjs, mean.io

I have created a package in `MEAN.IO` which has its own template by overriding the system package template

```
MyPackage1.register(function(app, auth, database, system) {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
});
```

Now I create the second package and want that package has its own template too, so I do the same for second package too

```
MyPackage2.register(function(app, auth, database, system) {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
});
```

But in this case I am getting the `MyPackage1` templates for `MyPackage2`.

If I depend the `MyPackage2` on `MyPackage1` as below

```
MyPackage2.register(function(app, auth, database, MyPackage1) {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
});
```

The template of `MyPackage1` override by the templates of `MyPackage2`